# What's wrong on this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm selecting total count of villages, total count of population from my tables to build statistics. However, there is something wrong. It returns me everything (530 pop (there are 530 pop in total), (106 villages (there are 106 users in total)) in first row, next rows are NULLs

[image]

```
SELECT s1_users.id userid, (

SELECT count( s1_vdata.wref ) 
FROM s1_vdata, s1_users
WHERE s1_vdata.owner = userid
)totalvillages, (

SELECT SUM( s1_vdata.pop ) 
FROM s1_users, s1_vdata
WHERE s1_vdata.owner = userid
)pop
FROM s1_users
WHERE s1_users.dp >=0
ORDER BY s1_users.dp DESC
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use joins?

Comment: dude, you are already using INNER JOIN in your sub-query ...

Comment: What does "Please, I do not want to use INNER not LEFT JOins, thanks" mean?  Do you want to use INNER and not LEFT, or LEFT and not INNER?  Also, a better requirement to give us is saying if you want to show userids with villages and populations or if you do not, since that is what affects whether or not you would user inner vs. an outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing s1_users from inner SELECTS

Comment: tell me, why did it do so strange things with one single additional unnecessary table?

Comment: if you put two tables in 'FROM', it is like you join them without a join clause! i.e. you have each record of first repeated for each record of the second one

Answer (score 2):

You're already using INNER JOINs. Whan you list tables separated with comma, it is a shortcut for INNER JOIN.

Now, the most obvious answer is that your subqueries using aggregating functions (COUNT and SUM) are missing a GROUP BY clauses.

```
SELECT s1_users.id userid, (

SELECT count( s1_vdata.wref ) 
FROM s1_vdata, s1_users
WHERE s1_vdata.owner = userid
GROUP BY s1_vdata.owner
)totalvillages, (

SELECT SUM( s1_vdata.pop ) 
FROM s1_users, s1_vdata
WHERE s1_vdata.owner = userid
GROUP BY s1_vdata.owner
)pop
FROM s1_users
WHERE s1_users.dp >=0
ORDER BY s1_users.dp DESC
```

However, using subqeries in column list is really inefficient.  It casues subqueries to be run once for each row in outer query.

Try like this instead

```
SELECT 
  s1_users.id AS userid,
  COUNT(s1_vdata.wref) AS totalvillages,
  SUM(s1.vdata.pop) AS pop
FROM
  s1_users, s1_vdata  --I'm cheating here! There's hidden INNER JOIN in this line ;P
WHERE
  s1_users.dp >= 0
  AND s1_users.id = s1_vdata.owner
GROUP BY
  s1_users.id
ORDER BY
  s1_users.dp DESC
```

Comment: You don't need a `GROUP BY userid`?

Comment: @genesis: Did try the version with, or without GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  s1_users.id AS userid,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    s1_vdata
        WHERE   s1_vdata.owner = userid
        ) AS totalvillages,
        (
        SELECT  SUM(pop)
        FROM    s1_vdata
        WHERE   s1_vdata.owner = userid
        ) AS pop
FROM    s1_users
WHERE   dp >= 0
ORDER BY
        dp DESC
```

Note that this is less efficient than this query:

```
SELECT  s1_users.id AS user_id, COUNT(s1_vdata.owner), SUM(s1_vdata.pop)
FROM    s1_users
LEFT JOIN
        s1_vdata
ON      s1_vdata.owner = s1_users.id
GROUP BY
        s1_users.id
ORDER BY
        dp DESC
```

since the aggregation needs to be done twice in the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid,totalvillages,pop   from 
(
SELECT s1_users.id as userid, count( s1_vdata.wref ) as totalvillages
FROM s1_vdata, s1_users
WHERE s1_vdata.owner = userid
GROUP BY s1_users.id) tabl1 INNER JOIN
(
SELECT s1_users.id as userid, SUM( s1_vdata.pop )  as pop
FROM s1_users, s1_vdata
WHERE s1_vdata.owner = userid
GROUP BY s1_users.id) tabl2 on tabl1.userid = tabl2.userid
```